# Complex IF formula

Tags: excel, if-statement, error-handling

I'm trying to build if formula that basically repeats itself with only 2 cells changing value on each instance.

```
=IF(AND(J12<50,J12<>””,K12=”Z02”,Q12=”Z3”),”Repl. Type does not match Planner”,
IF(AND(J12<50,J12<>””,K12=”Z02”,Q12=”Z4”),”Repl. Type does not match Planner”,
IF(AND(J12<50,J12<>””,K12=”Z05”,Q12=”Z3”),”Repl. Type does not match Planner”,
IF(AND(J12<50,J12<>””,K12=”Z05”,Q12=”Z4”),”Repl. Type does not match Planner”,
IF(AND(J12<50,J12<>””,K12=”Z06”,Q12=”Z3”),”Repl. Type does not match Planner”,
IF(AND(J12<50,J12<>””,K12=”Z06”,Q12=”Z4”),”Repl. Type does not match Planner”,
IF(AND(J12<50,J12<>””,K12=”Z07”,Q12=”Z3”),”Repl. Type does not match Planner”,
IF(AND(J12<50,J12<>””,K12=”Z07”,Q12=”Z4”),”Repl. Type does not match Planner”,
IF(AND(J12<50,J12<>””,K12=”Z08”,Q12=”Z3”),”Repl. Type does not match Planner”,
IF(AND(J12<50,J12<>””,K12=”Z08”,Q12=”Z4”),”Repl. Type does not match Planner”,
""))))))))))
```

I get `#Name?` error on this.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Add a few rows of your table

Comment: Note that `”` should be `"` as used in `Planner”,""))))))))))`.

Comment: Mrig, thank you.. I typed this formula in word cause I just found it quicker doing long formulas like this sometimes and did not pay attention. Thanks for spotting that

Comment: you can use =ifs()

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AND(J12<50,J12<>"",K12="Z02",Q12="Z3"),"Repl. Type does not match Planner",IF(AND(J12<50,J12<>"",K12="Z02",Q12="Z4"),"Repl. Type does not match Planner",IF(AND(J12<50,J12<>"",K12="Z05",Q12="Z3"),"Repl. Type does not match Planner",IF(AND(J12<50,J12<>"",K12="Z05",Q12="Z4"),"Repl. Type does not match Planner",IF(AND(J12<50,J12<>"",K12="Z06",Q12="Z3"),"Repl. Type does not match Planner",IF(AND(J12<50,J12<>"",K12="Z06",Q12="Z4"),"Repl. Type does not match Planner",IF(AND(J12<50,J12<>"",K12="Z07",Q12="Z3"),"Repl. Type does not match Planner",IF(AND(J12<50,J12<>"",K12="Z07",Q12="Z4"),"Repl. Type does not match Planner",IF(AND(J12<50,J12<>"",K12="Z08",Q12="Z3"),"Repl. Type does not match Planner",IF(AND(J12<50,J12<>"",K12="Z08",Q12="Z4"),"Repl. Type does not match Planner",""))))))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This formula seems way too long to me. Why not do this?

(I put in a few line breaks to increase readability.)

```
= IF(AND(J12<50,J12<>"",
         OR(K12={"Z02","Z05","Z06","Z07","Z08"}),
         OR(Q12={"Z3","Z4"})),
         "Repl. Type does not match Planner","")
```